# Possesives of Multiple Objects

Tags: possessives

How does one describe the possessives of multiple parties? For example the apples of Mark and the oranges of Fred.

Would it be:

> Mark and Fred's apples and oranges

Or perhaps:

> Mark's and Fred's apples and oranges

Would it be different if one were describing the apples of Mark and the apples of Fred?

Note: I am looking for a sentence of this structure in particular; not a rephrasing which avoids the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether the nouns are acting separately or together.

1. Use "**Mark's and Fred's** apples and oranges .. " if each of them owns these fruits.
2. Use "Mark and **Fred's** apples and oranges .." if they share ownership of the fruits.